# Emacs doesn't fully maximize in Linux Slackware

Tags: linux, emacs

Emacs version is 24.2.1, OS: Linux Slackware 14.0. I am using `fullscreen` function to maximize it on startup. Clicking maximize button does the same.

But I mentioned, that it is not fully maximized. Look carefully at the screenshot. You'll see the words "About Slackware and FreeBSD ,Who is Fast?" from Firefox.

[image]

How can I make it fully maximize?

Comment: The solution is here: http://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules_Application_Workarounds

Answer (score 1):

This code in `.emacs` works for me (Ubuntu 10.04) .. It uses two steps: emacs' maximize and then the Window Manager's maximize.

```
(require 'maxframe)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'maximize-frame t)
(defun maximize-wm (&optional f)
       (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
               '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT" 0))
       (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
               '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" 0)))
(maximize-wm)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Seems to be a KDE interaction problem.

Comment: The solution is here: http://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules_Application_Workarounds